# How to change gear with respect to speed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a small car racing game and want to increase gear with respect to speed. I didn't put an actual gear system in my car. To increase gear, I'm using the following logic where I'm able to see gear change from 0 to 1 but not any further.

```
var gr=0;
var sp=0;
sp=sp+(20*Time.deltaTime);

if(currentSpeed>=sp)
{
    gr++;
    gear.text="GEAR "+gr;//displaying gear          
}
```

Above, `currentSpeed` increases gradually with time.

Comment: It means that after one increment, your sp and currentspeed go hand in hand (equal) or sp always lower. Print values of currentspeed and sp for a specified time and compare

Comment: ok. I'll update you regarding that soon

Comment: It fluctuates between 0-1 and stays 0 at end

Comment: Please post sample values of current speed and sp for different times

Comment: my current speed varies like this `currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(currentSpeed, maxSpeed, Time.deltaTime); `  while moving car and maxSpeed is 100

Comment: please provide the sample values these functions generate. How would we know how much your Mathf.Lerp and 20*Time generates

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise using that method for determining what gear it is in based on speed. Look at this code:

```
int currentSpeed; //this will store your speed

int[] gearSpeeds = new int[]{40,80,120,160,220}; //set any number of gears and on what speeds will they switch to different gear
int currentGear = 1; //this is default value

for(int i = 0; i < gearSpeeds.Length; i++) //go through hearSpeeds array
    if(currentSpeed > gearSpeeds[i]) currentGear++; //if the gear is not enough for specific speed check next it finds the right one
    else break;
```

This is very simple way to solve this problem, you can easily change number of gears and on what speed they change.

Comment: my current speed varies like this  `currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(currentSpeed, maxSpeed, Time.deltaTime);`  while moving car and maxSpeed is 100

Comment: Don't see how that's relevant, just set the values that you want in gearSpeeds.

Comment: Thanks @NevenIgnjic, I had to change several things in your code since I'm using unityscript. It worked.

Comment: Oh forget to write it in JS, sorry. Anyway accept the answer if it helped you.